# Did Alita make enough for a sequel?

Tags: production, box-office, alita-battle-angel

Its budget according to google said it was 200 million. Worldwide in the box office it made over 400 million but I keep finding articles that say it may break even or even be a loss? How is that possible when it doubled its budget? Is it taxes not figured in? Was it a success? I loved the film. I dont want to see it be a golden compass and end without a sequel.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! You're asking multiple questions here, and some of them seem opinion based. Different people will have different opinions on what constitutes "financial success" or "enough to justify a sequel".

Comment: Another factor to consider is not all reported budgets include marketing which can often be about as much as production costs. I'm afraid I'm going to VTC, but don't be dissuaded. Happens to all of us. Please stick around; it's a pretty great community.

Comment: @K Gibson  The worldwide gross is the total amount paid to many thousands of theaters worldwide.  Each theater keeps a portion of that gross to pay expenses and possibly make a profit, and sends a portion to the distributor and/or the production company, according to various distribution deals.  The production company/companies only makes a profit if their share of the worldwide gross is larger than the production cost and marketing costs, and the film is only considered successful if the production company makes a significant profit.

Comment: If a company spends $200 million on a movie (and likely somewhere between $100-$150 million on advertising et al) just to barely earn back your costs. These kinds of movies are supposed to make a billion or so to kick off a franchise. (And Golden Compass was really bad and completely ignored the core of the book. Oh, and that book series is now a BBC/HBO series.)

Answer (score 3):

The *production budget* for the film was about $200 million, but that only covers the costs of actually making the movie.  That does not include other costs related to the movie, such as advertising budgets and interest paid to whoever funded the film.

Comment: I always thought that $400M was the theatre gross and the individual theatre's profits need to reduce it; aka artificially inflated for hype.